# iOS : perform task in background when app is force quit by user

Tags: ios

In iOS application, I want to upload data on server when internet available. Now problem is, if user has force quit the application then how I can re-invoke the application or can do task in background when internet is available? Is there any possible way in iOS?

Comment: It's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Apple is not allowing to run code after the user force quits the app. There are just some special rules to reactivate the app like blutooth implementation. For normal server task, you just can work while the user not force quits the app.

#### Edit

Not even with special rules you can reactivate your app. Bluetooth reactivation and co only works if the app gets killed by memory issues or something similiar. If the user force quits the app, the app will not run until next app start.

Answer (score -1):

The iOS will give you 3mins to run a background task. Take a look at https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/finite-length-tasks-in-background-ios-swift-60f2db4fa01b

Comment: 3 mins in background. His question is asking for a force quit. So its not possible to get 3 mins for Vikas